# YQL yahoo.finance.historicaldata EUR/USD

Tags: yahoo, yql, yahoo-finance

Is it possible to get a EUR/USD currency pair from the YQL yahoo.finance.historicaldata? I managed to get the "EUR=x" (results in USD/EUR) but how can i get a EUR/USD price to avoid calculating every price/inverting it?

This works fine: select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "EUR=x" and startDate = "2016-08-01" and endDate = "2016-08-04"

But not: select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "EURUSD=x" and startDate = "2016-08-01" and endDate = "2016-08-04"

I found these two great list with all yahoo stock tickers:

http://investexcel.net/all-yahoo-finance-stock-tickers/

But it looks like the webservices do not offer the inverted price (EUR/USD) only the EUR=X (USD/EUR) ? Is this the case?
http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote

Many Thanks
Micke

Comment: It seems that it's only possible to get from USD to any other currency, from what i've seen.